# Flatten list within RDD of tuples with type (List,Integer)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have an RDD of tuples with the format (List,Integer) in PySpark.

Example:

```
(["Hello","How","are","you"],12)
```

I want to convert this to an RDD of type

```
("Hello",12),
("How",12),
("are",12),
("you",12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flatMap`:

```
rdd.collect()
# [(['Hello', 'How', 'are', 'you'], 12)]

rdd2 = rdd.flatMap(lambda r: [(i, r[1]) for i in r[0]])

rdd2.collect()
# [('Hello', 12), ('How', 12), ('are', 12), ('you', 12)]
```

Comment: In this example, why does a map operation with the same lambda expression give an error when `take` is called on the result. Also, what would be the output for map instead of flatMap. Would it be `(("Hello",12),("How",12),("are",12),("you",12))`, i.e all results within one tuple?

Comment: @twothreezarsix sorry, I fixed a problem. `take` should also work now. Yes, your expected outcome for using `map` is correct.

Comment: What was the purpose of using [ ], instead of ( ) in the edit

Comment: @twothreezarsix that will result in a list rather than a generator.

Comment: One small doubt, why did `take` fail the first time with map. With flatMap, both [ ] and ( ) give the same result. So what changes with map?

Comment: `flatMap` evaluates the generator but `map` doesn't, and an RDD cannot contain a generator.